# Parsing XML does not select any nodes through SelectNodes method

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<products xmlns="http://www.fusepumpaffiliates.co.uk/feed-distribution/etsy/us/">
    <product>
        <title>Product 1</title>
    </product>
    <product>
        <title>Product 2</title>
    </product>
    <product>
        <title>Product 3</title>
    </product>  
</products>
```

The code below has worked with other XML files without any problems, so I fail to see why my code below does not work on this specific XML feed.
I can't even count the number of nodes:

```
Dim req As HttpWebRequest
Dim Resp As HttpWebResponse
Dim reader As StreamReader
Dim responseString As String = ""
'get the XML
Dim productXML As New XmlDocument
Dim node As XmlNode
Dim root As XmlNode

req = HttpWebRequest.Create(fpm.feedURL)
req.Timeout = 3600000 '3600 seconds
Resp = req.GetResponse()
reader = New StreamReader(Resp.GetResponseStream)
responseString = reader.ReadToEnd()

productXML.LoadXml(responseString)
Dim mgr As XmlNamespaceManager = New XmlNamespaceManager(productXML.NameTable)
mgr.AddNamespace("whatever", productXML.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI)
root = productXML.DocumentElement

nodeList = root.SelectNodes("/products/product")    

'nodeList.count = 0 here?!??!

For Each node In nodeList


        If node.SelectSingleNode("categories") IsNot Nothing Then   

        End If
Next node
```

Comment: In these cases, there is a proceeding which always works for me: firstly having a perfectly working simplistic version and then increasing its complexity/accounting for the proper inputs. For example: take a reliable simple sample code (MSDN ->https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcebdtae(v=vs.110).aspx; I think that you are using a different namespace; but you get the idea); write a simple input file (a few nodes ideally emulating the structure of the real inputs) and struggle with it until making sure that it works perfectly. Then you can scale it up as much as required.

Comment: Thanks! It was the namespace that was defined that caused the issue.

Comment: Well... actually speaking it was you rather than me.

Comment: Points for getting me on the right track though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently when a namespace is not defined in the XML, I can use any name for the namespace. But if there IS a namespace, like in my feed, I must use that namespace.
Now it works.